# Using SQL Server spatial queries, how to select a shape that is produced by intersecting two other shapes and calculate its area?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM dbo.BndPrimarySchoolZone b
WHERE b.ncessch IN ( 250315000417, 250315000421 );
```

It produces two rows, returning some descriptive data along with two shapes (`Shape` column is of data type `geometry`):
[image: query results]

In the "Spatial results" tab you can see that these two shapes overlap:
[image: overlapping shapes]

Question: how can I isolate just the overlapping area into a separate shape and calculate its area?

I have looked at [STIntersects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15), but that seems to only be useful for determining *if* the shapes intersect, and not for finding the actual intersection. I understand that once I have the intersection, finding its area is trivial with [STArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/starea-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after discovering the [STIntersection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersection-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) function, I think this works:

```
WITH cte_school1
AS (SELECT b.*
    FROM dbo.BndPrimarySchoolZone b
    WHERE b.ncessch = 250315000417),
     cte_school2
AS (SELECT b.*
    FROM dbo.BndPrimarySchoolZone b
    WHERE b.ncessch = 250315000421)
SELECT s1.Shape.STIntersection(s2.Shape),
       s1.Shape.STIntersection(s2.Shape).STArea()
FROM cte_school1 s1
    JOIN cte_school2 s2
        ON s1.Shape.STIntersects(s2.Shape) = 1;
```

If there is a better way to do it, please post in comments.

Comment: I don't see why you need the CTEs

Comment: @Charlieface, I would appreciate a suggestion on a better way to build a join between two rows of the same underlying table.

Comment: Just merge the `WHERE` into the main query `SELECT ..... FROM BndPrimarySchoolZone  s1 JOIN BndPrimarySchoolZone s2 ON .... WHERE s1.ncessch = 250315000417 AND s2.ncessch = 250315000421`